# Loop Code Error C++?

Tags: c++

This was an exercise question from a C++ programming book. There's a flaw in this loop code. I am sure a lot of people would the answer straightaway. I am guessing is with the prefix increment operator.

```
      int x = 0; 
      while (x)
      {
        ++x;
       cout << x << endl;
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

no, its `x=0;` 
you need to assign x to a positive number like `x=1` to get the loop running because `x=0` evaluates to false, so loop will not run.

Comment: @owacoder: actually, signed overflow is undefined behavior. The compiler is allowed to transform that loop into an infinite loop (and IIRC there was some gcc version that with -O3 did exactly this).

Comment: @MatteoItalia - I was mistaken. I was thinking of it as an `unsigned int`. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

If **x=0** the while loop will evaluate to false, and the body of the while loop will never be executed, since **x** will not be changed and always remain 0.

Nothing will be output, and the program will exit with a return code of 0, giving no clue to the lack of output.

Comment: while(x)  is interpreted as : while(x!=0) , so the nothing is output to the screen

Answer (score 0):

The while loop will not execute at all since 0 is treated as false

```
while(false){
//will not execute; since (x=0 == false)
}
//skips above code and execute this directly.
```

if you want to run code inside loop you can just give a true value like x=1;

```
while(true){
//will execute (since x=1 === true)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`while(1)` is equivalent to `while(x == 0)`, `while(0)` is equivalent to `while(x)`

The "**semantic**" is "**while**" running while .. and the variable "**x**" contains **0** so if it is added directly to the condition, as it is **0 = false**

**x == 0**, return true if `x == 0`.

..

```
return (x == 0);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot all of you for your time and input. Your answers were straight to the point, concise and easy to understand. The world is a better place with you.

Answer (score 0):

ref: https://www.tutorialcup.com/cplusplus/while-loop.htm

while(x) is evaluated as while(x!=0) so nothing will be output to the console. i.e. it is the same as:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{


    int x = 0;
    while (x != 0) 
    {
        ++x;
        cout << x << endl;

    }

    return 0;
}
```